# Apple Mach-O Linker Error ld: unknown option: -fobjc-arc

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, linker-errors

When I try to run my code on Xcode5, I get this error.

```
ld: unknown option: -fobjc-arc
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

However, I have not added `-fobjc-arc` anywhere in linker flags. What could be the reason causing this error?

Comment: `-fobjc-arc` is the flag to tell the compiler to build using ARC.  That option shouldn't be being passed to the linker.

Comment: Try doing a clean/cleaning the build folder (option-clean).